# ggplot Fill SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the U.S. counties SPDF and shade the counties that appear in another vector (matching by GEOID). This is the code I currently have, but none of the counties are shaded.

I have downloaded the ShapeFile of U.S. county borders from this [link](https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=Counties%20%28and%20equivalent%29).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
US_counties <- shapefile("~/us_county_shp_files/tl_2017_us_county.shp")
counties_in_radius <- c("12011", "12015", "12021", "12027", "12043", "12049", "12051", "12055", "12061")
base_plot <- ggplot(data = US_counties) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1.3) +
  geom_polygon(data=US_counties, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), size = 0.1, colour = "gray", 
               fill= (if(US_counties$GEOID %in% counties_in_radius) "blue" else NA))
base_plot
```

If I just do GEOID, I get the error object 'GEOID' not found, whereas when I do US_counties$GEOID, I get "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".

How can I properly fill the counties that are in counties_in_radius?

Comment: Fill needs to be assigned inside your `aes`, and you should do it with bare column names, no `$` notation